# create an XLS variable to show all field values that match certain condition in a SharePoint 2010 list

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Given the SharePoint list below:

```
Name    Age
Lisa    15
Joe     20
Nick    15
```

I can manage to create a XSL variable that counts rows where age is equal to 15

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
<xsl:variable name="KidsCount" select="count($Rows[@Age = 15])"/>
```

Now, I'd like to create the variable KidsNames with all names (concatenated) where age is equal to 15.

What should I put in the select part below?

```
<xsl:variable name="KidsNames" select="  ???   "/>
```

It is possible to add a new line or return char at the end of each name, so when printing the variable #kidsNames I get a sort of list of names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 or above, you can use `string-join()` :

```
<xsl:variable name="KidsNames" select="string-join($Rows[@Age = 15]/@Name, ',')"/>
```

But I believe Sharepoint 2010 only support XSLT 1.0, so here is possible XSLT 1.0 solution using `xsl:for-each` loop :

```
<xsl:variable name="KidsNames">
    <xsl:for-each select="$Rows[@Age = 15]">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: the <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/> won't print the value of Name. However, replacing that line by <xsl:value-of select=" 'yes' "/> will output as many 'yes' as elements satisfy the condition. How can I get the Name field value printed?

Comment: Found the issue. Despite having modified the default list field in SharePoint (from "Title" to "Name"), I still have to use "Title" so <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/> output the values of my Name field. Answer accepted.